# GLSL Sampler2D tiling issue

Tags: three.js, glsl

So I'm currently working on a post-processing shader that takes 8 textures and displays them in a tile like fashion on the screen. There are 8 tiles, that appear in 2 rows of 4. For most part I've gotten what I've needed working, however I'm running into a small issue with coordinate precision. Please take a look at the image below:

[image]

As you can see its for the most part working, with some minor wrapping of the texture on the outer x and y extremes of each tile. No doubt its my math that causing the issue.

This is basically the code for the GLSL fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse2;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse3;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse4;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse5;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse6;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse7;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse8;
varying vec2 vUv;

vec4 getPixelColor(vec2 coord) {

    //Output color
    vec4 color = vec4(.0, .0, .0, .0);

    //Obtain the division point between tiles
    float xDiv = 1.0 / 4.0;
    float yDiv = 1.0 / 2.0;

    //Which tile is it?
    int tileX = int(floor(coord.x / xDiv));
    int tileY = int(floor(coord.y / yDiv));

    float x = (coord.x - (float(tileX) * xDiv)) * 4.0;
    float y = (coord.y - (float(tileY) * yDiv)) * 2.0;
    vec2 tileCoord = vec2(x, y);

    //Set the current sample to the desired texture
    if (tileX == 0 && tileY == 1) color = texture2D(tDiffuse, tileCoord);
    if (tileX == 1 && tileY == 1) color = texture2D(tDiffuse2, tileCoord);
    if (tileX == 2 && tileY == 1) color = texture2D(tDiffuse3, tileCoord);
    if (tileX == 3 && tileY == 1) color = texture2D(tDiffuse4, tileCoord);
    if (tileX == 0 && tileY == 0) color = texture2D(tDiffuse5, tileCoord);
    if (tileX == 1 && tileY == 0) color = texture2D(tDiffuse6, tileCoord);
    if (tileX == 2 && tileY == 0) color = texture2D(tDiffuse7, tileCoord);
    if (tileX == 3 && tileY == 0) color = texture2D(tDiffuse8, tileCoord);

    return color;
}

void main() {

    //Output color
    vec4 color = vec4(.0, .0, .0, .0); 
    color = getPixelColor(vUv);

    //Output to render
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

For convienience I've provided the 4 texture tiles that I'm using on Google Drive: (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5BRDQX6tFRqRmFKRE5PNFJkYTg).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

**Edit 1:**

I forgot to mention that I was using THREE.js for the WebGL component. After some feedback I played with the wrap settings of the textures, but the problem persists.

Comment: did you use `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` wrapping for the textures?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Spektre, see my comment to the answer given below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`gl.texParameteri`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texParameter), to set the texture wrap paramters.

See the [Khronos OpenGL ES 2.0 documentation of `glTexParameteri`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/):

> GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE causes coordinates to be clamped to the range
>  `[1/(2*N), 1 − 1/(2*N)]`, where `N` is the size of the texture in the direction of clamping.

```
gl.texParameter(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameter(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

In three.js the texture wrap parameters can be set as follows (see [Texture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/Texture) and [Texture Constants](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/constants/Textures)):

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( textureFileName );
texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
```

This means the texture coordinates, which are passed to `texture2D` are clamped, if they are less than 0.0 or greater than 1.0. In fact, the 
`u` (`x`) coordinate is clamped to `[0.5/width, (width-0.5)/width]` and the `v` (`y`) coordinate is clamped to `[0.5/height, (hight-0.5)/height]`.

Your shader code can be simplified like this:

```
vec2 tile      = floor(coord.xy * vec2(4.0, 2.0));
vec2 tileCoord = coord.xy * vec2(4.0, 2.0) - tile;

int tileX = int(tile.x);
int tileY = int(tile.y);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I should have clarified that I'm currently using THREE.js for the WebGL component. That's my mistake. However checking the documentation, I applied the THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping (which appears to be default anyway) to the textures being used. Unfortunately its yielding the same result with the outer edges of each tile.

Comment: Actually, I had to clear the cache from my browser and your solution worked. It was the simplified code that did the trick.

Comment: The `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` definition does not look right to me. Did they change it or it is WebGL specific?  IIRC In standard OpenGL I am used to The `GL_CLAMP` had similar definition (but shifted by half pixel inside instead of full pixel) and was the default value. The `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` has no shift so it is inclusive interval `<0,1>`  Also `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` is extension so OpenGL implementation must support it (but I do not know of any modern one which does not have it these days)

Comment: Since the question is about Three.js it seems like the answer should also be in Three.js and JavaScript, not OpenGL and C

Comment: It's still not a three.js answer, it's now an WebGL which is still not what the question is about and not relevant to someone who only knows three.js but doesn't know webgl

Comment: @gman Of course, I agree with you, but on the other hand the three.js tag was added later and was not part of the original question.